# How to get pn-prid with PJSIP_HEADER in Asterisk dialplan

Tags: sip, asterisk, freepbx, opensips

In extensions.conf i have a context

```
[from-internal-custom]
exten => _X.,1,NoOp(Exec script)
exten => _.,n,System(go run /callkeep/tools/main.go -i ${CALLERID(num)} -p fcm -d PJSIP_HEADER(read,contact)}) 
same => n,Goto(from-internal,${EXTEN},1)
```

I can get the contact with this script, but i want to get pn-prid in a header like this

`Contact:<sip:alice@alicemobile.example.com; pn-provider=acme; pn-param=acme-param; pn-prid=ZTY4ZDJlMzODE1NmUgKi0K>;`

PJSIP_HEADER(read,contact) returns just sip:alice@alicemobile.example.com

i try PJSIP_HEADER_PARAM(Contact,header,pn-prid) this return null

Comment: Dcoumentation for `PJSIP_HEADER_PARAM` says "Currently, the only supported header is `From`"

Comment: Also `SIP_HEADER` returns the first found header by default. Check if there are multiple such headers being sent. It absolutely will not mutilate the value as you've described.

Comment: Tnks !!! i make a bash script to get info with pjsip show aor, its work but when app is in background im not able to get this info. There is a way to save this info in the astdb ou something ?